# EMF dangling reference when I save my model

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, eclipse-emf

I have created a model with EMF and I would like to be able to save my model with the editor and open it later.
For the example let's say that my model has 3 classes: A, B, C and R. The R is the root parent. The class C has a reference to A and one to B.
When I edit my model everything works fine. But if I want to save my file to another location, I can open it but I can't save it anymore without getting an error message telling me that my references in my C object are dangling references.
The xml file when saving looks like this for my reference:

```
<refToA ="//@CompElement.0/@composit/@parts.0">
```

I tried to set containable to true in my ecore file. Dangling references disappear but after a save if I touch attribute of B that the changement doesn't apply to the reference because now I have two B object.

How can I make properly a reference and save it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
in my XMI file model was saved like this :

```
<R>
  <C refA... refB...>
  <\C>
  <A><\A>
  <B><\B>
<\R>
```

reference need to be place after saving A and B object like this :

```
<R>
  <A><\A>
  <B><\B>
  <C refA... refB...>
  <\C>
<\R>
```

Answer (score 0):

> my model has 3 classes: A, B, C and R

you mean your metamodel has 3 EClasses/metaclasses A, B, C and R.

> The R is the root parent

The root element of your model is of type R.
How are A, B and C contained?

> When I edit my model everything works fine. But if I want to save my file to another location, I can open it but I can't save it anymore

I doubt simply saving your Resource to a location or another has a significant impact on your model. How are you editing it and saving it to another location?

Comment: Yes I got confused between model and metamodel, I have 4 classes (not 3) A,B,C,and R. R can contain objects of A, B and C. And C must be able to refer to objects of type A and B already created. Now with editor if I create my model and save it, it creates dangling references.
The error log indicates dangling ref comes from references in C.

Comment: How do you setup the references in element c1 of type C towards instances of A and B?